# Laravel middlware array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel.

I want to pass an array to my middleware in my api so I can check that a user has a certain role. This is my idea:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next,$role)
    {
        $employee = Employee::find($request->parameters[0]['userid']);

        foreach($role as $r) {
            if (!$employee->hasRole($employee, $r)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'result' => [
                        'message' => 'Error creating Employee'
                    ]
                ], 500);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

But how can I pass an to my middleware. Right now I'm doing this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:Administrator,intern'], function () {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass a string as a middleware argument, but you can use PHP to convert a string to an array using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($request->parameters[0]['userid']);

    foreach(explode(',', $role) as $r) {
        if (!$employee->hasRole($employee, $r)) {
            return response()->json([
                'result' => [
                    'message' => 'Error creating Employee'
                ]
            ], 500);
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```